# How do I get access to the Youtube API Members endpoint?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've been told that you (youtube-api, #youtube-data-api, and #youtube-v3-api) might be able to assist me with accessing a specific API to build some exciting features. The API in question is the YouTube Data API, specifically the "members.list" endpoint, which you can find more information about here: YouTube Data API - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/members/list
.

I've encountered an issue while trying to access this endpoint, as it has prompted me to acquire additional permissions in order to retrieve the data I need. I would greatly appreciate it if you could provide guidance or assistance in obtaining the necessary permissions to access this API.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.  you need to use Oauth2 to request consent of the user who owns the data to access it.